# sub directories display using hadoop commands

Tags: shell, unix, hadoop

I have a hadoop directory format like

```
Main_Path/Category/Year/Month/Day/Hours=00/Part-0000
Main_Path/Category/Year/Month/Day/Hours=01/Part-0001
Main_Path/Category/Year/Month/Day/Hours=02/Part-0002
Main_Path/Category/Year/Month/Day/Hours=03/Part-0003
```

I want to get output like below format

```
        Main_Path/Category/Year/Month/Day/Hours=00
        Main_Path/Category/Year/Month/Day/Hours=01
        Main_Path/Category/Year/Month/Day/Hours=02
        Main_Path/Category/Year/Month/Day/Hours=03
```

I tried with below commands

```
hadoop fs -ls -C Main_Path
```

o/p:-

```
Main_Path/Category/Year/Month/
```

but am getting only two sub directories

my expected output like below

```
            Main_Path/Category/Year/Month/Day/Hours=00
            Main_Path/Category/Year/Month/Day/Hours=01
            Main_Path/Category/Year/Month/Day/Hours=02
            Main_Path/Category/Year/Month/Day/Hours=03
```

Comment: I think you want `ls -R MainPath`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below command:

hadoop fs -ls -R / | grep "^d"

As such there is no hadoop command to stop with directories.